# Is there a way to do partial average over matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

I have a matrix (table actually) which  I imported from a file:

```
    1.0000    1.9736
    4.0000    0.2016
    9.0000    0.0584
   10.0000    0.0495
    5.0000    0.1845
    2.0000    0.6873
    1.0000    1.4177
    2.0000    0.4699
    5.0000    0.1555
   10.0000    0.0435
   13.0000    0.0326
    8.0000    0.0860
    5.0000    0.1685
    4.0000    0.1956
    5.0000    0.1433
    8.0000    0.0675
   13.0000    0.0335
   13.0000    0.0327
   10.0000    0.0431
    9.0000    0.0582
   10.0000    0.0551
   13.0000    0.0308
```

I want to get the average of each of the occurance on left column. That is:

```
avg = [
  1.0000    1.69565
  2.0000    0.5786
  4.0000    0.1978]
```

and so on. I could do this with a wile or for group but this is not the matlab way. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=[randi(5,10,1) rand(10,1)];
```

a =

```
4.0000    0.4387
1.0000    0.3816
2.0000    0.7655
1.0000    0.7952
1.0000    0.1869
5.0000    0.4898
4.0000    0.4456
2.0000    0.6463
5.0000    0.7094
1.0000    0.7547

[uniqueID,~,uniqueInd]=unique(a(:,1));
[uniqueID accumarray(uniqueInd,a(:,2))./accumarray(uniqueInd,1)]
```

ans =

```
1.0000    0.5296
2.0000    0.7059
4.0000    0.4422
5.0000    0.5996
```

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is called `a`, try

```
>> accumarray(grp2idx(a(:,1)),a(:,2),[],@mean)
ans =
       1.6957
       0.5786
       0.1986
      0.16295
      0.07675
       0.0583
       0.0478
       0.0324
```

Note that `grp2idx` is part of Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have that, you can use the `unique` command to get the same results.

Comment: Thanks. This is going to run on a comutaion server and I don't know what is installed on that machine. I won't be able to use your solutions. Sorry